How can i have the processor process consistently in Bull-queue
I am using GCP. when my app is on app engine, the process intermittently runs into the error of "Missing process handler for job type postMentionNotification". It has definitely succeeded every once a while.
in my local environment it happens less frequently.
  @Process({ name: postMentionNotification, concurrency: 1 })
  async handlePostMentionNotification(job: Job<PostMentionNotificationDto>, ) {
    this.logger.log(`Processing mention job ${job.id}: ${JSON.stringify(job.data)}`);
    const notification: PostMentionNotificationDto = job.data;

  ...
  }

it often occurs to this process. I am using nestJS as backend.
I have tried to move the process into the same class as the queue, it does not help. It only happens to this one process consistently. I thought it could be dependency injection issue. it is certainly not given other process can run without a problem in the same worker class. I am thinking it's a redis issue, but it just happens to this one process.
